# Nodemon Server won't restart

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, visual-studio-code, nodemon

The Nodemon is not restarting every time if there is any changes in the file, I need to stop the server with Ctrl-C and start the server again. I'm on Windows 64bit, I have changed in line 30, yet the server is not restarting. Why is it not restarting?

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyparser =require('body-parser')

const app = express();
app.use(bodyparser.json());


const database = {
    users:[
        {
            id:'123',
            name:'john',
            email:'john@gmail.com',
            password:'cookies',
            entries:0,
            joined: new Date()
        },
        {
            id:'124',
            name:'sally',
            email:'sally@gmail.com',
            password:'bananas',
            entries:0,
            joined: new Date()
        }
    ]
}

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.json(database.users);
})


app.post('/signin',(req,res)=>{
    if(req.body.email === database.users[0].email && req.body.password === database.users[0].password){
        res.json('success');
    }
    else{
        res.status(400).json('error logging in');
    }

})


app.post('/register',(req,res)=>{
    const {name , email , password} = req.body;
    database.users.push({
            id:'125',
            name:name,
            email:email,
            password:password,
            entries:0,
            joined: new Date()

    })
    res.json(database.users[database.users.length-1])
})


app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("listening to port 3000");
})
```

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "Backend-brain-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "ts-node": "^8.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

If I define a start script inside package.json it gives me a whole new error:

```
> Backend-brain-api@1.0.0 start D:\Nitin\Node.js & Express.js\Backend-brain-api
> nodemon server.js

'Express.js\Backend-brain-api\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Nitin\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Backend-brain-api@1.0.0 start: `nodemon server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Backend-brain-api@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Could not reproduce (albeit on macOS) - if I copy your `package.json` and `server.js` to a new directory, run `npm i && npm start`, then edit the `server.js` I see nodemon restart it as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a Windows path thing. Windows was not able to get the path as it had unnecessary special characters like the `&` and the whitespaces in the path names. Looks like Node is not able to resolve the paths.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling nodemon using this:
npm install -g nodemon

If you are using nodemon v2.0.20 and if in linux system, then try this:
nodemon -L -V server.js

It's watching each files of the present working directory as we are using the -L option, which stands for legacyWatch & -V for verbose which shows the details of what causes restart.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of typing nodemon server.js in your terminal, type npm start. This should execute the start script in your package.json and hence run nodemon on server.js.

Hope this helps

Comment: I am running ```npm start``` still not wokring

Comment: And in your terminal you're in the same directory as your package.json?

Comment: yes i am running the terminal in the same directory

Comment: Could you pass a link to a github repo?

Comment: Off-site code links should only be supplemental, the [mre] must be *in the question*. Encourage editing, not linking.